# Notification when buildbot worker is down

Tags: buildbot

It happens quite often that a buildbot worker is down and it usually takes a little until someone notices.
Is there a way in buildbot to receive a notification if a worker is down?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on the version of Buildbot you're using, the notify_on_missing parameter is what you're looking for. (https://docs.buildbot.net/1.8.0/manual/configuration/workers.html#when-workers-go-missing)